# send and accept parameters inside POST in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, post

I have basic question but I really cannot find simple answer. I am new to Laravel. I am trying to create POST method in controller.

**Javascript**

```
var url = "ling/public/translation/add";
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: ko.toJSON(self.wordToAdd)
        });
```

**Route**

```
Route::controller('translation', 'TranslationController');
```

**TranslationController:**

```
public function postAdd()
{
    return 1;
}
```

My problem is that I cannot understand how to get parameters from body inside Controller method (`postAdd`). I am sending model in `JSON` format. I am used to programm in .NET C# and inside there I would write like this:

```
public function postAdd(Translation $translation)
{
    // and then use $translation->category_id ...
    return 1;
    }
```

I mean that I would send JSON and .NET would automatically deserialize JSON into class Translation ($translation variable).

How to do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel does support dependency injection. In the case of `public function postAdd(Translation $translation)` it will attempt to instantiate a `Translation` object, but will not know anything about your `json`. In this context you would use the `Request` object and then decode the `json`:

```
public function postAdd(Request $request){

   // Pass the second paramater as true to return an associative array
   $translation = json_decode($request->data, true);

   // build your Translation object from the json

   return 1;
}
```

If you are just looking to save `Translation`, I would expect that once you've decoded you json it would be in the correct format, so you should be able to do:

`App\Translation::create($translation);`

It's also important to note that Laravel requires `posts` to include the `csrf token`, so you will need to pass this inside your ajax, I can see you are using `knockoutjs`, so you could wrap this up in a custom binding, something similar to:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.postJson = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var values = valueAccessor() || {};
        var token = values.token;
        var wordToAdd = values.data

        var json = ko.toJSON(wordToAdd);

        $(element).on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'translation/add',
                method: 'post',
                data: {'data' : json, '_token': token },
                success : function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error : function(e){
                  console.log('Error! '+ e);
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

And then bind this to your page element:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Word" data-bind="postJson : {token : '{{ csrf_token() }}', data : $root.wordToAdd }" />
```

Comment: But what if I have removed from middleware csrf file? Can I do this?

Comment: If you have removed the `VerifyCsrfToken` class from the middleware in `app\Http\kernel.php` then the token should not be required and you can leave it out. Although, it is quite useful, so I would leave it in unless there is a reason not to.

Comment: In any case, I am getting "BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 744: Target [App\Http\Requests\Request] is not instantiable." exception now. I have added use App\Http\Requests\Request; inside Controller. Maybe here is some problem.

Comment: But if I remove this use, I get "Class App\Http\Controllers\Request does not exist"

Comment: I think that should be `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`